# CakePHP Shell "could not start" from Scheduled task and Windows 2003 Server

Tags: cakephp, scheduled-tasks, cakephp-2.2, windows-2003-webserver, cakephp-2.3

I am trying to run a CakePHP Shell script through the Scheduled Task of Windows 2003 server and I'm finding that the task *Could not start*.

When I run it manually from the Command Prompt it works well:

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CakePHP\lib\Cake\Console\cake mail read
```

The Scheduled task Run field is exactly the same and the *Start in* is set to:

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\tickets\app
```

The *Run as* field is set as the computer admin which has all permissions (not the ISS user)

Scheduled Task log shows this message when trying to execute it:

> "Ticket Mail System.job" (cake) 13/12/2012 07:15:00 ** ERROR **
>
> Unable to start task.
>
> The specific error is:
>
> 0x80070005: Access is denied.

It seems it is a permissions problem.

I have tried to give over the `lib/Cake/Consol/cake.bat` file all permissions for both users, the *IIS 6* user and the *Internet Guest Account* user, but still doesn't work.

Any idea which could be the cause?

Comment: If you google the error code ("scheduled task 0x80070005"), there's a ton of troubleshooting to try: check event log, make sure it's running as an admin (that your admin user truly is part of the admin group), make sure task directory has correct permissions, make sure cmd.exe does, etc.

Comment: I already tried those things :)

Comment: Got it! Hmm.. have you tried running as an IIS user and giving that IIS user permission to cmd.exe? (Not that admin shouldn't work...)

Comment: Yeah, I tried it :) I played with permissions over `cmd.exe` and `cake.bat`. Nothing worked. But now I found the solution. Its in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked well over Windows 7 but it didn't on Window 2003 Server.

Finally, I tried it adding `.bat` after calling the Shell and it works.

I had to put this in the *Run* field:

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\CakePHP\lib\Cake\Console\cake.bat mail read
```

It seems Windows 2003 needs the `.bat` at the end...

I found it at: http://www.geekyboy.com/archives/376

Comment: Huh, that's odd - I never had that problem. Windows has never needed the `.bat` extension for me, it always just recognized that it should use that file. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, this got my issue solved.

found that my ".bat" file instead had the extension ".CMD" which seemed to work fine up until now.

fixed it by renaming the file extension and changing the directory in the task scheduler.(because it still had the ".CMD" extension.